# Retrofit 2 interceptors has private access

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor, okhttp

I'm following this post: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

and trying to add an interceptor as follows:

```
package test.com.testretrofit2;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.IOException;

public class InterceptorTest {

  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
      @Override
      public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
          Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

          // Do anything with response here

          return response;
      }
  });
}
```

However, on the line

```
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
```

I get an error

```
'interceptors' has private access in com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.
```

I'm using

```
com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1
```

and it's pulling in okhttp-2.5.0.  I've looked in OkhttpClient.java and interceptors() is public.

Am I using the wrong Retrofit 2.0 library or version?

Comment: I got the same code 'client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() ' working fine with the retrofit version 2.0.0 beta1. So there is no trouble with the retrofit version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (the truth of the matter) --

Your code need to be in a method, not just in the class.

```
public class InterceptorTest {

  void myTest() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
      @Override
      public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        // Do anything with response here

        return response;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Edit (another possibility) --

Turns out you can also see this error if you have an unterminated scope in the code the comes before this code.  For example,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

  });
client.interceptors().add(new SigningInterceptor());
```

Will show the error you indicate in the IDE, but will give many more errors on compiling.  Note that the `Runnable` is not terminated correctly in this example.  It is missing a `}`.  Check to make sure your `{}` are where they are supposed to be.

Original option --

Your error and the code you posted do not match.  If the function had private access, you should get an error that says --

```
'interceptors()' has private access in com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.
```

note the ()'s.

It is important in this case, because `OkHttpClient` has a private member named `interceptors`, but a public `interceptors()` method.

One would expect the error you see for this line --

```
client.interceptors.add(new Interceptor() {
```

Note this missing ()'s after `interceptors`.  Double check your code in all places you call `interceptors` to see if you missed the parentheses.

Comment: The error refers to 'interceptor' and not 'interceptors()'  I didn't miss the parentheses in my code, either.   It's as shown above.

Comment: I am still thinking there is a syntax error somewhere.  What code do you have immediately above that code?  Is it possible you have an unterminated anonymous object? See edit

Comment: I edited the original post to add the entire class.  No doubt there is a syntax error in there somewhere.

Comment: Oh, for Pete's sake!  I couldn't see the forest through the trees!

Comment: happens to the best of us!  I didn't see it when I first looked at your edit.  If this solves your issue, could please mark this answer as accepted?